# Why is the component not being rendered in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

So I've learned react, but I need some help while practicing on it. this might be a long one but your help would be appreciated. none of the following code worked so I just want to find out what I'm doing wrong.
 I set the following context which is an array of objects

```
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react';

export const Songlist = createContext()

const TheSongs = (props) => {
    const [songs, setSongs] = useState([
        {title: "deliverance", artist: "opeth", id: 0},
        {title: "civil war", artist: "guns n roses", id: 1},
        {title: "heaven and hell", artist: "black sabbath", id: 2},
        {title: "anesthetize", artist: "porcupine tree", id: 3}
    ])
    const songList = () =>{
        setSongs(songs.forEach(song =>{
            return(
                <div className="container" key={song.id}>
                    <h4>{song.title}</h4>
                    <h3>{song.artist}</h3>
                </div>
            )
        }))
    }
    return ( 
        <Songlist.Provider value={songs, songList}>
            {props.children}
        </Songlist.Provider>
     );
}

export default TheSongs;
```

Then i tried to call it in a component like that

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {Songlist} from '../contexts/TheWorld'

const SongListUI = () => {

    const {songList} = useContext(Songlist)


    return ( 
        <div className="hi">
            {songList}
        </div>
     );
}

export default SongListUI;
```

No errors occured, however nothing was rendered at all and the div called "hi" contained nothing.

Then I just kept the array in the context and called it in the component by use Context again but this time I tried something different, and that is

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {Songlist} from '../contexts/TheWorld'

const SongListUI = () => {

    const {songs} = useContext(Songlist)

    const songList = () =>{
      songs.forEach(song =>{
        return(
            <div className="container" key={song.id}>
                <h4>{song.title}</h4>
                <h3>{song.artist}</h3>
            </div>
        )
    })
}

    return ( 
        <div className="hi">
            {songList}
        </div>
     );
}

export default SongListUI;
```

I got an error that says that functions are not allowed as react childs and still nothing was rendered in the div so I tried something different again, I applied the `forEach` loop inside the `jsx` instead of the name of the function and still it didn't work and nothing was rendered inside the "hi" div. so i took off the whole context and used the `useState` hook inside the component itself

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const SongListUI = () => {

    const [songs, setSongs] = useState([
        {title: "deliverance", artist: "opeth", id: 0},
        {title: "civil war", artist: "guns n roses", id: 1},
        {title: "heaven and hell", artist: "black sabbath", id: 2},
        {title: "anesthetize", artist: "porcupine tree", id: 3}
    ])

    const songlist = () =>{
        setSongs(songs.forEach(song =>{
            return(
                <div className="container" key={song.id}>
                    <h4>{song.title}</h4>
                    <h3>{song.artist}</h3>
                </div>
            )
        }))
    }


    return ( 
        <div className="hi">
            {songlist}
        </div>
     );
}

export default SongListUI;
```

didn't work because of the react child error again, so

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const SongListUI = () => {

    const [songs, setSongs] = useState([
        {title: "deliverance", artist: "opeth", id: 0},
        {title: "civil war", artist: "guns n roses", id: 1},
        {title: "heaven and hell", artist: "black sabbath", id: 2},
        {title: "anesthetize", artist: "porcupine tree", id: 3}
    ])


    return ( 
        <div className="hi">
            {
                songs.forEach(song =>{
                    return(
                        <div key={song.id}>
                            <h4>{song.title}</h4>
                            <h3>{song.artist}</h3>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
     );
}

export default SongListUI;
```

and still nothing works, so I just want to know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: You have used `forEach` everywhere to return the result, [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) don't return anything but `undefined`, you should use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which will return your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `forEach` is `undefined`. Can you try your last example with `.map` on your songs instead?

i.e.

`songs.map((song) => <div key={song.id}><h4>{song.title}</h4><h3>{song.artist}</h3></div>)`

Comment: Awesome, Thanks. but what about the context? is something wrong with it, or should I also replace forEach with map?